# Vue reactive component props

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, reactive

I have method in my component that adds popup and passing some props into its.

```
openPopup () {
    this.$store.dispatch('addPopup', {
      component: MapCropsPopup,
      props: {
        anchor: this.$refs.filter,
        selectedCropIds: this.selectedCropIds,
        activeSeason: this.activeSeason,
        onBeforeClose: () => {
          this.$router.push(this.getQuery({ showCrops: null }));
        },
        onSeasonChange: (season) => {
          this.activeSeason = season;
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Here, in child component i store all passed props into 'props' variable

```
props: ['props']
```

and use them directrly in template

```
<div class="mcp-seasons__btn"
           :class="{ 'm--active': props.activeSeason === 'current' }"
           @click="setActiveSeason('current')">
        {{ i18n.CURRENT_LABEL }}</div>
```

To update current season in parent component I use method setActiveSeason

```
setActiveSeason (season) {
  this.props.onSeasonChange(season);
}
```

it works good, and updates 'activeSeason' in parent component, but won't update same property in child component.

What should I do to **make property reactive again**?

Comment: how do you create a child component and pass props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
    selectedCropIds: this.selectedCropIds,
    activeSeason: this.activeSeason,
```

you are making nonreactive members of an object that are initialized to the given values at the time. If, instead, you did something like

```
    propParent: this
```

and in the popup component referred to `props.propParent.activeSeason`, you would be using the reactive item.

Comment: Hmmm, how would this work with the composition API?

Comment: @qotsa42 I do not know.